# How to insert python list into a column in database

Tags: python, sql

My python list with name **final_data_path** containes below links, which I need to insert into the **other_file_url** column in **transactions.batch_upload** but it is only updating the list name not the links. Refer screenshot below. Please suggest.

```
[
    "https://link/split/1.csv",
    "https://link/split/2.csv",
    "https://link/split/3.csv",
    "https://link/split/4.csv",
]
```

here is my query.

```
UPDATE 
  Transactions.batch_upload 
SET 
  other_file_url = 'final_data_path' 
WHERE 
  batch_upload_id = '23232'
```

[image]

Comment: Changed it to lower case. Thanks for advice.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one* tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: you have a python list(column is sql) and you want put this value into a column of table.Am I right? – RF1991   ---- Yes, want to put this complete value in a column

Comment: It is just a list

Comment: Yes, a single row like below---  [ ' ' , ' ' , ' ' , ' '  ]

Answer (score 0):

the length of *other_file_url*  and its *Data Type* must be in accordance with *final_data_path* (Python list)

```
declare @t varchar(max)=(select final_data_path from yourtable)
UPDATE 
  Transactions.batch_upload 
SET 
  other_file_url = @t /*Or following comment query*/
WHERE 
  batch_upload_id = '23232'
```

or more simply

```
UPDATE 
  Transactions.batch_upload 
SET 
  other_file_url = (select final_data_path from yourtable)
WHERE 
  batch_upload_id = '23232'
```

Comment: Did above query worked?